# IdentityServer4 Client is not Authenticated by HttpContext.SignInAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

My Identity server code is like below to set temp cookie

```
var claims_list = new List<Claim>();
claims_list.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user.UserId.ToString()));
claims_list.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
claims_list.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username));
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims_list, "2FA", user.Username, "user");
string _TwoFactorAuthenticationScheme = "idsrv.2FA";
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme: _TwoFactorAuthenticationScheme,
    principal: new ClaimsPrincipal(id));

return Redirect("https://localhost:44315/Home/Index");
```

And in the client MVC application, the index action is like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)  //Always user is detected as Not Authenticated
    {
    }
}
```

The startup.cs for Client application is like below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ConsentCookie.IsEssential = true;
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddAutomaticTokenManagement()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.ClientSecret = "thisisapassword";
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/home";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.Scope.Add("api1");
        //options.Scope.Add("affiliation");
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("website", "website");
    });

    services.AddMvc(opt =>
    {
        opt.Filters.Add(typeof(AffiliationFilter));
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();


        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

Not sure how this is not authenticating a user at the client application. IS some changes needed in client configuration?
In my case, Identity server and MVC client are 2 separate projects and i am trying to set a temp cookie at identity server-side and let the user to enter some additional validation details from another project and if all of them are correct, then only redirect the user to identity server project and allow actual login.

```
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.Username, user.UserId.ToString(), user.Username));
```

This is the code i am used to allow the user to Login but only after the successful  second round validation from a different project . Till the time i am planning to keep user validated by setting the temp cookie

Comment: I wonder why you are setting the cookie yourself in the first place? Just having `AddOpenIdConnect` with the proper settings is enough to authenticate against IdSrv4. No need to set claims principal yourself. Did you check your IdSrv4 / client logs to be sure everything is correct? i.e. correct audience, expiration date, return url etc?

Comment: @Tseng As i am trying to explained in my last part of question , I am implementing a  2 Factor Auth using Identity server and using this temp cookie to validate user temporarily for entering the token user received at email or sms.

Comment: You don't really need a cookie for that. Why not using IdSrv4 with ASp.NET Core Identity? It already ships with 2FA code (you just need to add javascript library to generate the QR Code)

Comment: Have to validate user based on custom database tables and conditions and not possible to use Net core Identity for the purpose and also needs to include an option for sms / email-based verification for login.  The problem now is after login from identity server we are redirecting to  a different project for entering token on mail or sms . BUt the Identity server is marked as logged in at this stage and to avoid this we are trying to implement the temporory cookie

Comment: All that stuff is possible with ASP.NET Core Identity. SMS/email based verification is built-in already, i.e. `options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount` (only users with confirmed email can login), you can extend IdentityUser via inheritance and `AddDbContext<T>` overloads and `SignInManager`/`UserManager` have virtual methods for overriding and can be configured. On Identity Server side you can deny access via `IProfileService.IsActiveAsync` (if it returns false its treated as if user is disabled/not allowed to login/access the token service endpoint)

Comment: and you have the IDentity Stores as extensibility too https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/UserStoreBase.cs via the `IUser*Store` interfaces